# What does "collapsing to unique 'x' values" mean in this example?

Tags: r, ggplot2, unique, warnings

The example plot below produces a warning about

```
In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values
```

and I cannot figure out what that means in my example.

It must be related to the `5`, because the warning disappears when replacing `5` by `4` or `1`.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1, y = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 5))
ggplot2::ggplot(df, ggplot2::aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    ggplot2::geom_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.5))
```

What is going on here?

Comment: I'm curious to know the answer to that. However, I noticed that removing `draw_quantiles = c(0.5)` also stops the warning; so I'm thinking maybe this argument has some sort of problem with the `5` outlier?

Comment: @ÉricoPatto yes, I tend to minimize my code examples - anything left in there is of relevance. `draw_quantiles = c(0.5)` would not be in there if it did not matter ;)

Comment: I have filed https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4455

Comment: I think the problem is https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/cc3951cd942d2b1621a21f4b3c6ca5e76284e10e/R/geom-violin.r#L200, where the estimated density is passed as `x` to `stats::approxfun`. `stats::approxfun`, in turn, is concerned about ties in `x`. So the problem seems to be that the far outlier in `df$y` leads to zero density and thus flat cumulative density. I could imagine that `ecdf <- stats::approxfun(dens, data$y, ties = "ordered")` would get rid of the warning, although I'm unsure if that gives the correct result (but I am unsure of that currently, too).

Comment: Yep I came to the same conclusion as @bers. Printing `density(df$y)$y` will show a stretch of zeros around the 282th element. There is also https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4120 which proposes to calculate quantiles based on observations instead of the densities.

Comment: This shoujld be fixed with `ggplot2` 3.4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@teunbrand confirmed my hypothesis that

```
ecdf <- stats::approxfun(dens, data$y)
```

(https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/cc3951cd942d/R/geom-violin.r#L200) is to blame.

Zeros in the `density` of the `data$y` translate into equal values ("ties") in the cumulative density `dens` - hence the warning.

These zeros can be avoided by `adjust`ing the bandwidth of the density (here, slightly - in my example, I need to use a value as large as `3`):

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1, y = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 5))
ggplot2::ggplot(df, ggplot2::aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    ggplot2::geom_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.5), adjust=1.1)
```

Note: that code is hard to read due to niceties such as using `dens` for the *cumulative* density.

But `stats::regularize.values` is not necessarily better:

```
    x <- xy.coords(x, y) # -> (x,y) numeric of same length
    y <- x$y
    x <- x$x
```

The problem also can be fixed by

```
ecdf <- stats::approxfun(dens, data$y, ties = "ordered")
```

as in this monkey patch:

```
create_quantile_segment_frame <- function(data, draw_quantiles) {
  dens <- cumsum(data$density) / sum(data$density)
  ecdf <- stats::approxfun(dens, data$y, ties = "ordered")
  ys <- ecdf(draw_quantiles) # these are all the y-values for quantiles

  # Get the violin bounds for the requested quantiles.
  violin.xminvs <- (stats::approxfun(data$y, data$xminv))(ys)
  violin.xmaxvs <- (stats::approxfun(data$y, data$xmaxv))(ys)

  # We have two rows per segment drawn. Each segment gets its own group.
  ggplot2:::new_data_frame(list(
    x = ggplot2:::interleave(violin.xminvs, violin.xmaxvs),
    y = rep(ys, each = 2),
    group = rep(ys, each = 2)
  ))
}
assignInNamespace("create_quantile_segment_frame", create_quantile_segment_frame, "ggplot2")

df <- data.frame(x = 1, y = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10))
ggplot2::ggplot(df, ggplot2::aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    ggplot2::geom_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.5), bw = 0.1)
```