# R problem with regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties)

Tags: r, message, regularized

I would like to ask a question

My code in R:

```
a=1.1
b=1.3


C=c(0,0.3,1.5,3.5,19.5)
v2=c(0.00, 0.56, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00) 


fun <- 
  function( C, a, b ){
    1 / (1 + (C / a)^b) 
  }


x_d=seq(0,10,by=0.1)
y_s <- fun(v2, a, b)  
y_d <- splinefun(v2, y_s)(x_d)
y_d <- approx(v2, y_s, xout = x_d)$x
which(y_d <= 0.5)
which(y_d <= 0.5)[1]
x_d[which(y_d <= 0.5)[1]]
```

I'm getting a warning messages:

```
 y_d <- splinefun(v2, y_s)(x_d)
Warning message:
In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties)) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values
> y_d<- approx(v2, y_s, xout = x_d)$x
Warning message:
In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values
> which(y_d <= 0.5)
[1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
> which(y_d <= 0.5)[1]
[1] 11
> x_d[which(y_d <= 0.5)[1]]
[1] 1
```

I would like to improve my code so that I don't get such a warning messages. It ruins the results for me. However, I wouldn't want to remove the duplicate values of v2 and its results, I need them later.

I do not hide that it is important for me to find a way where I can use non distinct values for v2 and treat them as if they were unique and continue to use them in my code. Is there such a way in R? Thank you in advance for any help with this problem. I am quite new to R so please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "collapsing to unique 'x' values" mean in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67298243/what-does-collapsing-to-unique-x-values-mean-in-this-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is a problem with your function `fun()`. It only has one argument (`variables`), but you feed it more than one object (`v2, a, b`). But if I fix it to the below, I can reproduce your error message:

```
fun <- 
  function( C, a, b ){
  1 / (1 + (C / a)^b) 
}
```

If you simply want to avoid the warning messages, you can use [`ties = "ordered"` or `ties = mean`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67298243/what-does-collapsing-to-unique-x-values-mean-in-this-example) with functions `splinefun()` and `approx()`. [Please read here under "Details" if `ties = "ordered"`, `ties = mean`, or something else is best for your specific programming goal](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/approxfun).

```
a=1.1
b=1.3
C=c(0,0.3,1.5,3.5,19.5)
v2=c(0.00, 0.56, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00) 

fun <- 
  function( C, a, b ){
    1 / (1 + (C / a)^b) 
  }

## no ties specified
x_d=seq(0,10,by=0.1)
y_s <- fun(v2, a, b)  
y_d <- splinefun(v2, y_s)(x_d)
#> Warning in regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties)): collapsing to unique
#> 'x' values
y_d <- approx(v2, y_s, xout = x_d)$x
#> Warning in regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm):
#> collapsing to unique 'x' values
which(y_d <= 0.5)
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
which(y_d <= 0.5)[1]
#> [1] 1
x_d[which(y_d <= 0.5)[1]]
#> [1] 0
rm(x_d, y_s, y_d)

## ties specified
x_d=seq(0,10,by=0.1)
y_s <- fun(v2, a, b)  
y_d <- splinefun(v2, y_s, ties = "ordered")(x_d)
y_d <- approx(v2, y_s, xout = x_d, ties = "ordered")$x
which(y_d <= 0.5)
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
which(y_d <= 0.5)[1]
#> [1] 1
x_d[which(y_d <= 0.5)[1]]
#> [1] 0
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer jrcalabrese. Could you please explain to me why
  which(y_d <= 0.5)
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
which(y_d <= 0.5)[1]
#> [1] 1
x_d[which(y_d <= 0.5)[1]]
#> [1] 0

I get these results because I think they're are  incorrect  results and I'm new to R?

Comment: I actually get the same output (`[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6`) regardless of whether `ties` is specified. I've updated my answer to include both outputs, when `ties` is and isn't specified.

Comment: Thank you very much could you tell me why it gets the same output ([1] 1 2 3 4 5 6) regardless of whether ties is specified?  I don't get it.

Comment: With the data that you have, `ties` doesn't seem to effect the output in any way, but [as described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56861001/how-to-suppress-warnings-from-statsregularize-values), the `regularize.values` warning will always occur if `ties` is missing.

Comment: Thank you, which means that with these repeating data in  v2 I can't get other results for splinefun and approx or is there some other way  with may be  other function with similar use or something  I don't know about?  Please answer it is extremely important to me

Comment: Should I use a different functions  with repeating data in v2  or something else?

Comment: This question is about the regularize.values warning — if you have a new/different question, you should make a new post.